# Org-babel. :flags in C code blocks dont work correctly anymore

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, c++, c

I'm trying to run current code block

```
#+HEADERS: :includes <math.h> <stdio.h> :flags -lm
#+HEADERS: :var x=1.0 :var y=4.0 :var z=10.0 
#+begin_src C  :tangle trying
double pi = 4*atan(1);
double r, theta, phi;
r = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
theta = acos(z/r) * 180.0/pi;
phi = atan2(y,x) * 180.0/pi;
printf("%f %f %f", r, theta, phi);
#+end_src
```

And when I try to execute this code, I got an error:

```
/tmp/ccPySR8b.o: In function 'main':
C-src-uM2yPq.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to 'sqrt'
C-src-uM2yPq.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to 'acos'
C-src-uM2yPq.c:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to 'atan2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess, this happened, because babel put the flag before filename `gcc -lm code.c`, instead `gcc code.c -lm`. I don't know how to fix it.

Org mode version 9.1.4
GNU Emacs 27.0.50

In fact, I tested this code block on different PCs, and this case have 100% reproducibility.

**UPDATE**

`-lm` must be used with `:libs` option, not `:flags`, thx @NickD

Comment: I can not reproduce, Emacs 25.2.2,  Org 9.1.2. Concerning gcc, both  gcc -lm code.c  and gcc code.c -lm work -> this is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: I can not reproduce it with GNU Emacs 27.0.50 and Org mode version 9.1.4 (release_9.1.4-206-g4b80c6). I get #+RESULTS:\n: 10.816654 22.406871 75.963757.

Comment: What does the C file (presumably /tmp/C-src-uM2yPq.c) look like?

Comment: Nick, like [that](https://hastebin.cuttlerat.ru/epakeyehaf)

Comment: So, I checked right now, gcc 5.4.1 and 6.4.0 behave the same way

Comment: Vincent, I don't know, what the  gcc you use, but version 7.2.0 returned `undefined reference`, when I use `gcc -lm <filename>` and works correctly, when `gcc <filename> -lm`. So, IT IS the cause. Sorry for my anger, but RTFM, plz.

Comment: @РоманЗайруллин: your anger is misplaced. I have gcc 7.2.1 and both  `gcc -lm <filename>` and `gcc <filename> -lm` work correctly for me. I don't know why you are getting the error you are getting, but can you please try `gcc -Wl, -lm <filename>` and report whether it works or not?

Comment: Also try `#+HEADERS: :includes <math.h> <stdio.h> :libs -lm` with `:libs` instead of `:flags`; that should put the `-lm` at the end where your gcc will not complain. But it would still be interesting to find out why your gcc complains, whereas other gcc's do not.

Comment: Are you running on Linux? If so, which distro?

Comment: @Nick Here is seance with gcc: https://hastebin.cuttlerat.ru/ I'm running on Ubuntu 17.10, Elementary 0.4.1, Ubuntu 16.04. (3 different PC's). With :libs this case work correctly! Thanks! I don't know, how I missed :libs argument in doc.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear, as at least four of us can't reproduce the problem. It may be something unusual/non-standard about OP's version of gcc?

Comment: @Tyler updated.

Comment: I can reproduce it now, so I've retracted my close vote. I posted an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by an old version of gcc. I tangled your code to create a source file named `trying.c`. It compiles just fine with the `-lm` flag before or after the filename with a recent gcc:

```sh
gcc -lm trying.c # compiles without error
gcc trying.c -lm # compiles without error
gcc -v # -> gcc version 8.2.0 (Debian 8.2.0-3)
```

When I try to run the same code on an older Ubuntu distribution, it fails as you describe:

```
gcc -lm trying.c
/tmp/cc7tRgsC.o: In function `main':
trying.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `sqrt'
trying.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `acos'
trying.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `atan2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```sh
gcc trying.c -lm # compiles without error
gcc -v # -> gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8~14.04.2)
```

Your original org-mode file compiles just fine on a computer with a recent version of gcc.

As you've discovered, setting the `-lm` argument using the `libs` option rather than the `flags` gets you around the issue. This *might* be a bug in `org-mode`, but I'm not familiar enough with C programming to be sure about the difference between `libs` vs `flags`.

Answer (score 0):

In org-mode we must pass multiple header files as a list, see code below:

```
  #+header: :var x=1.0 :var y=4.0 :var z=10.0
  #+BEGIN_SRC C :results output  :flags -lm :includes '(<math.h> <stdio.h>)
  double r=0.0;
  double theta=0.0;
  double phi=0.0;
  double pi = 4.0 * atan(1);
  r = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
  theta = acos(z/r) *180.0/pi;
  printf("%f %f %f", r, theta, pi);
  #+END_SRC  

  #+RESULTS:
  : 10.816654 22.406871 3.141593
```

Comment: 1) List don't need anymore. (tangled correctly) and 2) U'r version have same error.